# How do I replace a whitespace with any number of whitespaces?

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to build a regex expression using `boost::regex` (my version of GCC doesn't handle `std::regex` particularly well).

I want to replace any occurrence of whitespaces with `\s*` so that it'll match any number of whitespaces (I don't care if the number of whitespaces differs).

Here's an example:

```
std::string s = "this is a test string";
s = boost::regex_replace(s, boost::regex("\\s+"), "\\s*");

std::cout << s;
```

This produces:

> thiss*iss*as*tests*string;

What I *want* is `this\s*is\s*a\s*test\s*string`. Why isn't this working?

I tried replacing with `\\\\s*` but that just produces `this\\s*is\\s*a\\s*test\\s*string`, also not what I'm after!

Comment: This is pretty interesting. With `boost::regex` I get the behaviour you describe, but with [`std::regex`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9edd5ae8e61302cc) I don't.

Comment: @Rapptz ah... That is interesting.

Comment: Hmm, [I can't reproduce this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8bff05212a28789). Which version of boost are you using?

Comment: Coliru's is [1.55](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a26d43e990508f94). That might be why?

Comment: I'm not sure why boost.regex makes you escape `\s` for the replacement string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very satisfying solution, but based on the comments I'm thinking this might be an issue with my version of `boost` (1.53). To get around this issue I simply nuke all whitespaces:

```
stringToMatch = boost::regex_replace(stringToMatch, boost::regex("\\s+"), "");
expression = boost::regex_replace(expression, boost::regex("\\s+"), "");
```

This has the same effect, so I'm going with it for now, but it's certainly not ideal!

Comment: As a workaround, try passing `boost::regex_constants::format_literal` as the fourth argument to the `regex_replace` call.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to gain a lot from using a regex in this case. With one (probably minor) proviso, it's pretty easy to do this without them (though matching the result against a string will pretty much require regexes).

```
std::string input = "this is a test string";

std::istringstream buffer(input);

std::ostringstream result;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(result, "\\s*"));

std::cout << result.str();
```

Result: `this\s*is\s*a\s*test\s*string`.

This uses the `infix_ostream_iterator` from [another post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

The proviso: this doesn't (currently) attempt to deal with whitespace at the beginning and/or end of the result pattern. In most cases, these aren't necessary, but if you want to add them, doing so is pretty trivial.